# Power Variation on the Time Energy Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The time-energy uncertainty principle is typically formulated in quantum mechanics as:

$\Delta E \Delta T \ge h/4\pi$

Where ΔE is uncertainty in energy, and ΔT is the standard deviation in the time taken for the expectation value to change. By dimensional analysis, it would appear from a crude analysis that the above equation is equivalent to:

$\Delta P \Delta T^{2} \ge h/4\pi$

If:

$\Delta P = \Delta E / \Delta T$

Is the second expression correct? My memory of my quantum mechanics class is rusty, but I believe there is a subtlety here I am not accounting for.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta E$ and $\Delta T$ mean two different things in the two equations.

In the first equation, you might have a photon or electron. You want to know the values for $E$ and $T$. It is impossible to know them exactly. There is an inherent uncertainty to both. You can arrange things so one uncertainty is small, but that necessarily increases the other uncertainty. $\Delta E$ and $\Delta T$ are the uncertainties.

In the second equation, you might have a process that produces energy. $\Delta E$ is the amount of energy produced in time interval $\Delta T$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. Just to be explicit, you are saying that is is NOT correct to express something like a power uncertainty ΔP as the quotient of the uncertainty in energy, ΔE, and the uncertainty in time, ΔT?

Comment: You would use propagation of errors to calculate the uncertainty of a derived quantity. See [Uncertainties and Error Propagation](https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html)